# How to cancel a stale site move on Google Search Console

Tags: google, google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect

I had two domain names, say A and B, pointing to the same domain, say C. I requested a "site move" from Google for them about a year ago and it's still not processed, so I believe it never will be. Now I want to stop those site moves, and instead have site C move to site A.

The [Change of address tool](https://search.google.com/search-console/settings/change-address) for site C shows:

> One or more of your other sites is moving to this site
>
> LEARN MORE

[image: screenshot of target domain]

Domain B has lapsed and I can no longer cancel the move. Domain A looks like it has no move settings:

[image: screenshot of source domain]

I tried to request another move from domain A to C, but because domain A now has its own server (I want to move domain C do domain A), the validation fails on the 301 redirects:

[image: validation failed]

How can I cancel a site move when Google doesn't let me do it easily?

Comment: You have to put redirects first on your server. So if site A should go to C, you must establish the corresponding 301 redirects. The tool instructs you that it can't find the redirect to verify your migration.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran Sorry for the confusion. I want to move domain C to domain A. I've set up the 301 redirects from C to A, but Google won't let me cancel the move from site A to site C, which I need to do before moving site C to site A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reference from the Official Search Console Support Guide:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220?hl=en-GB#cancel
[image: Solution]

You may need to wait several hours after setting up the 301-redirects. In the worst case, you may need to wait a few months, up to a year, for the site move to be cancelled and for you to be able to move it again.

Comment: Thank you Dhairya. I have tried those steps and Google won't let me cancel the move.

Comment: Have you waited several hours after removing the 301-redirect?